# Windows 7 dual-boot to Virtual Machine with VirtualBox (on Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, multi-boot

I wanted to ask if there's any way to have Windows 7 currently running in dual-boot, to be shared with VirtualBox (5.0.36) running on Ubuntu 16.04? 
I rarely use it, but I still have some applications that won't run on Wine, that I need to use sometimes. At the moment I just reboot, but I thought it would be good to be able to run it without rebooting, using VirtualBox.

The reason I want to "share" this Windows installation rather than simply convert is that I also use Windows to play some games and I believe VirtualBox will have performance issues with that.

So, quickly summarizing - I would like to have Windows 7 (64-bit) running both in dual-boot (this currently works just fine) AND in VirtualBox. This of course means I need to keep my Windows on physical partition.

Not sure if that makes any difference, but these are my HDD partitions:

1. sda1 - primary - swap
2. sda2 - extended with 3 logical partitions listed below
3. sda5 - logical - ext4 - root (+ boot with grub2)
4. sda6 - logical - ext4 - /var
5. sda7 - logical - ext4 - /home
6. sda3 - primary - ntfs - Windows 7 here

If this is possible, and I guess it is, are there any risks of doing this strictly related to having Windows running both on bare-metal and in VirtualBox? I could always go another way and use my Ubuntu in VirtualBox, if that seems safer.

Comment: I think you may run into an issue with the Windows license when it's running in VirtualBox. It might lose its activation as it will think it's running on a different machine than it was originally activated on.

Comment: @n8te right, this may be an issue... well, as far as I've done some research it seems the least of my problems with that, compared to things like drivers problems, etc. since Windows 7 lacks "hardware profiles". Would you suggest going another way around and using my Ubuntu with VM on top of Windows at the times I need both?

Comment: Why not just running a second Windows installation in VirtualBox? From your description of the problem I don't see a need for the two machines to be the *same* machine.

Comment: I have the exact same question. I boot to Windows, but I sometimes have to and for me it's a pain to reboot the machine because I have to set up all my windows, programs etc. on reboot. I'd also like to share any programs, changes etc. on my Win partition/boot with the ones in the virtual machine, that's why I'd like these two to be the same.